# why does not shown the holders number and transfers of the custom ERC20 token in Ropsten?

Tags: erc-20, ropsten

I published an ERC 20 token on Ropsten. The token's total supply, name and symbol shows on the self page (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/..) but **the holders number and transfers are not shown. The holders is zero and transfers section is empty...**

why can this happen?

thank you,

Comment: Did you verify your contract on Etherescan? That would be a likely reason.

Comment: Also the link in the question does not work.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you didn't add the `Transfer` event. Those are part of the standard and should definitely be implemented, see e.g. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#events.

A pretty good reference to use would be https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I solved this problem. I added the transfer event but I didn't trigger the transfer event. I made this. and then showed the holders count :)